# BUG in system.log, DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client. Strange things in system report

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash, kernel

MacBook Pro 13" Mojave 10.14.6
2.3 Ghz 8 GB RAM 512 GB Memory
intel I5 (4 cores)

I believe I accidentally deleted an important file days ago. Since, the CPU has been riding high, unit is very warm and battery fading. I believe a crash is going to happen soon. The idle wake ups in the activity monitor are tens of thousands, even seeing 1.4 million idle wake ups on kernel task.

I've erased and restored the computer at Apple today, and that seemed to work until I got home and it's started all over again. There is no extra software running (anti viruses or anything). I have done SMC and PRAM resets. Now, in the Console system log I've found this:

```
DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: Setting timer interval to 0 requests a 1ns timer, did you mean FOREVER (a one-shot timer)?; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug
```

```
Feb  1 20:00:41 Graysons-MBP xpcproxy[602]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 529: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
Feb  1 20:06:02 Graysons-MBP xpcproxy[605]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 529: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
Feb  1 20:09:21 Graysons-MBP syslogd[39]: ASL Sender Statistics
Feb  1 20:09:46 Graysons-MBP xpcproxy[607]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 529: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
```

```
Feb  1 19:29:15 Graysons-MBP Installer Progress[67]: Progress Updated: currentPhase = "loginwindow Boot", progress = 10.0, adjusted progress = 64.0
Feb  1 19:29:15 Graysons-MBP Installer Progress[67]: Progress Updated: currentPhase = "loginwindow Boot", progress = 25.0, adjusted progress = 70.0
Feb  1 19:29:15 Graysons-MBP Installer Progress[67]: Progress Updated: currentPhase = "loginwindow Boot", progress = 50.0, adjusted progress = 80.0
Feb  1 19:29:15 Graysons-MBP loginwindow[89]: USER_PROCESS: 89 console
Feb  1 19:29:15 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.501): com.apple.pluginkit.pkd (lint): Service sets EnableTransactions=false and EnablePressuredExit=true, which makes no sense. Enabling Transactions.
Feb  1 19:29:15 Graysons-MBP coreauthd[252]: objc[252]: Class TKTokenRefImpl is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security (0x7fffa0da4098) and /System/Library/Frameworks/LocalAuthentication.framework/Support/ModulePlugins/ModuleACM.bundle/Contents/MacOS/ModuleACM (0x10d131f30). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Feb  1 19:29:15 Graysons-MBP coreauthd[252]: objc[252]: Class TKTokenRefCtkd is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security (0x7fffa0da40c0) and /System/Library/Frameworks/LocalAuthentication.framework/Support/ModulePlugins/ModuleACM.bundle/Contents/MacOS/ModuleACM (0x10d131f58). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100008.Aqua): com.apple.AirPlayUIAgent (lint): EnablePressuredExit is not compatible with KeepAlive=true. Ignoring EnablePressuredExit.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.AirPlayUIAgent): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.usernoted): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100008.Aqua): com.apple.quicklook.ui.helper (lint): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.UserEventAgent-Aqua): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imklaunchagent): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.routined): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.routined): Unknown key for Boolean: EnabledPressuredExit
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.coreservices.UASharedPasteboardProgressUI): Unknown key for Boolean: DrainMessagesAfterFailedInit
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100008.Aqua): com.apple.scopedbookmarksagent.xpc (lint): Unknown key for array: com.apple.private.tcc.allow
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100008.Aqua): Caller tried to import service with same label as an existing service: path = /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.pluginkit.pkd.plist, caller = loginwindow.89
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100008.Aqua): com.apple.notificationcenterui.agent (lint): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Feb  1 19:29:16 --- last message repeated 3 times ---
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.notificationcenterui.agent): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.diagnostics_agent): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.PubSub.Agent): The ServiceIPC key is no longer respected. Please remove it.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100008.Aqua): com.apple.Dock.agent (lint): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Feb  1 19:29:16 --- last message repeated 7 times ---
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100008.Aqua): Could not import service from caller: path = /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.eospreflightagent.plist, caller = loginwindow.89, error = 138: Service cannot be loaded on this hardware
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100008.Aqua): com.apple.universalaccessd (lint): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.ap.adservicesd): Invalid type for environment variable value (env/type): MallocMaxMagazines/int64
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100008.Aqua): com.apple.VoiceOver (lint): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100008.Aqua): Caller tried to import service with same label as an existing service: path = /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.ctkd.plist, caller = loginwindow.89
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100008.Aqua): com.apple.ReportCrash (lint): Unrecognized MachService property: DrainMessagesOnCrash
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.soagent): Invalid type for event events
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.soagent): Invalid type for event bundleid
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100008.Aqua): Caller tried to import service with same label as an existing service: path = /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.storeinstallagent.plist, caller = loginwindow.89
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100008.Aqua): com.apple.AssistiveControl (lint): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.passd): Unknown key for string: com.apple.application-identifier
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.colorsync.useragent): Unknown key for string: RunLoopType
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100008.Aqua): Caller tried to import service with same label as an existing service: path = /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.trustd.agent.plist, caller = loginwindow.89
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.sharingd): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.sharingd): The endpoint "com.apple.private.alloy.nearby-idswake" defined in plist already exists and is owned by: com.apple.rapportd
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100008.Aqua): com.apple.corespeechd (lint): EnablePressuredExit is not compatible with KeepAlive=true. Ignoring EnablePressuredExit.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.corespeechd): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100008.Aqua): com.apple.ReportCrash.Self (lint): Unrecognized MachService property: DrainMessagesOnCrash
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100008.Aqua): com.apple.warmd_agent (lint): Assuming EnablePressuredExit=false given EnableTransactions=false.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100008.Aqua): com.apple.DwellControl (lint): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.gamed): The ServiceIPC key is no longer respected. Please remove it.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100008.Aqua): com.apple.universalaccesscontrol (lint): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.icdd): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.corespotlightd): Unknown key for dictionary: NoEnvironmentVariables
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100008.Aqua): com.apple.midiserver (lint): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.ap.adprivacyd): Unknown key for double: StartInterval
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.voicememod): Unknown key for Boolean: EnabledPressuredExit
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100008.Aqua): com.apple.noticeboard.agent (lint): EnablePressuredExit is not compatible with KeepAlive=true. Ignoring EnablePressuredExit.
Feb  1 19:29:16 Graysons-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.noticeboard.agent): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
```

Answer (score 1):

The message you highlight is not a bug in your system. It is supposed to be there, and it is not the cause of your problems with high CPU usage and fading battery.

I would suggest using Activity Monitor to identify which process or processes are actively using your CPU. These would be the causes of high CPU usage.

As you have already reinstalled, you might find that the CPU heat is not a by-product of high CPU usage, but rather a hardware problem (such as a cooling issue).